# Changing the default file path for icons in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, icons

On a WPF project, if I have an image and click on 'Source' and then 'Add' I get the choice to import images into the project. Is there a way of changing this file location?

VS2010 currently defaults to the "Libraries / Pictures" setting. I'd rather not change where this library points to as I don't store icons and pictures together.
After a bit of research I set up a new Windows library (useful article [here](http://lifehacker.com/5464350/get-to-know-windows-7-libraries-inside-and-out)) for icons but I can't work out how to set VS to default to the icons library I created, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) on my machine when doing this, I see the following:

Calls to RegOpenKey, RegQueryKey aimed at:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32
```

This seems to be a list of the last projects I've added/opened in Visual Studio. To test this, I added a project from a different location to my solution, then tried to change the source of the image.

Sure enough, the dialog defaulted to that location.

Your mileage my vary, but certainly, on my machine, the behaviour seems tied to what project I opened last. You can use Process Monitor to monitor devenv.exe while you choose an image on your machine to see what happens.

Given this, though, it would seem that you can't change this behaviour, although you can influence it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to have a look at that. 
I've also tried deleting the Pictures library from the library list but it didn't seem to make any difference and it defaulted to the My Documents picture folder. I'll just have to put up with it.

Comment: You are welcome - it was very interesting to look at. This is one of those things, that, when you have to add lots of things over time, becomes really annoying. One day, people will remember to make all of these behaviours configurable :-)